# How to limit bitrate for NGNIX RMTP server

Tags: nginx, module, rtmp

We have an NGINX RMTP module installed and while testing the same we came to know that the bitrate for the output was a around 7Mbps irrespective of the input stream's bitrate and as we have a lot of people watching these streams I would like to know how to reduce the same to about 4Mbps for this module?

Also, does NGNIX's RTMP module support H.265 instead of the standard H.264 which can help set the bitrate to about 2Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

You can transcode the incoming rtmp stream with ffmpeg with `maxrate` & `b:v` in this case you can control the maximum bitrate. Here is a simple example(for this example use another app show as well):

```sh
application live { 
    live on;  
    exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$app/$name -async 1 -vsync -1
        -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -maxrate 3000k -f flv -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/show/$name_with_maxrate
}
```